# Why does this span have a bigger height than it's parent

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a progression throught the site bar and I'm having a problem. There are **four span elements** that represents the sections of the frontpage, when you click on one of them it scroll to that section position. The problem is for some reason, **the span element are taller than the div cointaining** it, and for that, I can't align it vertically. It ain't a problem until you try to use the website on smaller resolutions, in wich, the span elements overflows the div.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2CIs.png) is what I'm talking about

See that the right attribute is because of a script that positioned the span according to the section position.

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFUs0.png) is where the problem became obvious

Here is the HTML :

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner" style="position: relative; top: auto;">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

                <div id="progressDiv"> 
                    <span id="progBar">
                    </span>
                    <div id="SectionsPos"> 
                      <a href="/#features">
                        <span id="novedPos" class="sectPos"> Novedades </span>
                      </a>
                      <a href="/#about">
                        <span id="redesPos" class="sectPos tooBig"> Redes Sociales </span>
                      </a>
                      <a href="#ProductosPrinc">
                        <span id="prodPos" class="sectPos"> Productos </span>
                      <a href="#Contacto">
                        <span id="contPos" class="sectPos"> Contacto </span>
                      </a>
                    </div>      
                </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS :

```
    #progressDiv {
    display: block;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-color: #d9b25f;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10vh;
}

#progBar {
    height: inherit;
    display: block;
    width: 0%;
    background: #d9b25f;
    max-width: 100%;    
}


#SectionsPos{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    height: 10vh;
    margin-top: -5vh;
}

.sectPos {
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white!important;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Excuse my English, it is not my native language, if there is something that it's not completely clear please let me know and I'll  try to explain myself better

Comment: please post all of the menu code here

Comment: what i understand is that you want that menu to be responsive and also looks like you are using bootstrap for that. But you are not making good use of bootstrap here. Let me know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: Try setting min-height to the parent div, that way span will never be taller. Unfortunately we can't help more unless you publish your code.

Comment: i posted some pictures with the code but i think someone edited the post and deleted them, i'll upload the rest of the code in a minute, thanks for the help

Comment: I want it to be responsive, i want the span elements to be vertically aligned inside the menu

Answer (score 0):

I kind of solved it but it is not an actual solution but a way to a avoid the problem, i changed de vh for pixels units, aparently you cant do what i wanted to do using vh units